# What exactly is なんだと?

Tags: words, particle-と, phrases

Is `なんだと` [what]+[quoting particle] like `なんだと(言った). Is nanda being quoted?

Answer (score 2):

なんだと! means "What!" なんだと言った doesn't make sense. なんと(orなんて)言った? makes sense and it is translated as "What did you say?"